# Web project : Back and Front

Tags: web, frontend, backend

I have to build a web project as a medium size project.
I need that the app will be responsive( Desktop\ mobile and etc.)
The processes will include chat, appointment system, monitoring system, reporting about conditions and etc.
I need a basic logic on the server side as a basic BI system.

I would like to receive recommendations about the languages.
For the front, I think about: HTML5+Angular
Backend: NODEJS or PHP

Any reccomandations?

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to go native when working with mobile but if you have already decided on a responsive website then I always prefer PHP as a backend but agree with you for HTML5 and Angular for front.

Comment: What is the reason for PHP and not NODE?

Comment: https://www.netguru.co/blog/nodejs-vs-php there a plenty of websites comparing the two such as this one. it is normally down to personal preference, I like php because I have used it in the past and there are plenty of tutorials and help available

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is pretty run-of-the-mill - you can practically build anything with both nodejs, php, angular or react. It could be very interesting discussing special projects that node or php work better for - but these are very rare.

You should be concerned with: who is writing the code, who is maintaining it, what will your deploy cycle look like, things like that.

If and you are comfortable with angular and php, then you should consider finding the leanest bootstrap libraries for angular and php. The next question you should ask yourself is what the bootstrap should contain out of the box - things you DON'T want to deal with:

- Authentication and Authorization
- UI bootstrapping
- Database (persistent data) abstraction
- so many other things.

Finally-  if you want a cool approach that really cuts down development times, go for serverless: https://serverless.com/, https://martinfowler.com/articles/serverless.html